# How to write a Rest API to return the same string that is sent by user

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

I am writing a Rest API for school assignment using C# that does nothing. It just sends back the same exact string sent by the user. This is my code:

```
namespace Textsender.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/send")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SenderController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public int ReturnString(string str)
        {
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

However, in Postman, when I use this command:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/send/ReturnString?str = "book"
```

I get `404 Not Found`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Small mistakes here, first the route to controller is incomplete, you need to include action (basically gets auto-replaced by a method name).

```
[Route("api/send/[action]")]
```

ReturnString() returns int, it should return string.
Fix those two and it should work.

Comment: 204 probably means str was null, set a breakpoint and check it. The quotes in your query may be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to NIKER's comment, remove the spaces and quotes from your postman URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/send/ReturnString?str=book
```

Comment: Thank you, mr.coffee. Your coment solved the "204 no content" problem!